Power BI Chart with Value not Count
I need help with a Device status chart.. I am exporting the status of some devices every hour to a table. I want to track them via some sort of graph.. doesn't have to be the same as the example below but anything that will show the same thing in some way would be great.
Example Graph image :

I have tried playing around with the data by adding to a visual, but I just keep getting counts and not the name values.
I have 2 tables btw.. 1 with Current(Newest Status) and then one that maintains the history.
DeviceStatusHistoryTable:
CheckDateTime       Status  Name
9/4/2024 4:21:31 AM Online  Device1
9/4/2024 4:21:31 AM Offline Device2
9/4/2024 4:21:31 AM Online  Device3
9/4/2024 5:25:31 AM Online  Device1
9/4/2024 5:25:31 AM Offline Device2
9/4/2024 5:25:31 AM Offline Device3
9/4/2024 6:30:31 AM Online  Device1
9/4/2024 6:30:31 AM Online  Device2
9/4/2024 6:30:31 AM Online  Device3
9/4/2024 7:20:31 AM Online  Device1
9/4/2024 7:20:31 AM Offline Device2
9/4/2024 7:20:31 AM LostConnection  Device3

DeviceStatusCurrentTable:
CheckDateTime       Status  Name
9/4/2024 8:22:31 AM Online  Device1
9/4/2024 8:22:31 AM Offline Device2
9/4/2024 8:22:31 AM Online  Device3


I don't know a way to have the text as values in the chart. The only solution I can think of is to create a numeric column with the statuses:
Device status = 
IF(
    'Table'[Status] = "Online", 3, 
    IF(
         'Table'[Status] = "Offline", 2,
         IF(
            'Table'[Status] = "LostConnection", 1)))

And you use this column on the Y axis. From your example, I assume that at every point in time, one device has only one status. So you can use any aggregation (except for count).
The resulting chart will have numbers instead of labels on the Y axis. What you can do, is eliminate the numbers on the axis and add text boxes with the actual labels. Not very elegant, but it's the only way I see. Here is the chart without the text box labels:

I hope this helps!
